# Bloomberg (Excel) Adjust Best estimates (BEST_EPS) from fiscal to calendar year

Tags: excel, bloomberg

I am making a comp sheet with forward estimated and am trying to adjust for the various fiscal years by converting metrics to the calendar year.
I know you can do this with historic data but I was wondering if it is possible to do with something like Best_EPS or a similar forward looking metric?

I attempted to adjust =BQL(“XXX US Equity”, “is_eps(fye=‘C’,fpt=A)”)
To work with BEST_SALES and BEST_EPS.
I also tried to play around with
BDP(xxx is equity,“BEST_EPS”, “Best_fperiod_overide=xxx)
changing the override tag from fy to bf etc. but they all seem to be based on the fiscal year.
Trying to read through the BQLX stuff but I am getting more lost.

Comment: BDP + Best_fperiod_override (with 2 R) should work as expected. Post the exact formula you have used.

Comment: =BDP(“8697 JP Equity”, “BEST_EPS”, “BEST_FPeriod_OVERRIDE=0FY”).  This formula produces the EPS estimate for fiscal year 2023, which ended in March 2023. Is there a way to adjust this to calendar year 23?

Comment: This really is a question the help desk should solve in less than 30 minutes. If you don't know, you can reach them by pressing F1F1

Comment: I don’t get a ton of time on terminal so was hoping to solve outside of my limited time but if the help desk is my only option I will use it. 
Thanks